# Remove or resize an image when selecting an item in a Picker view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to remove or resize the image from the tag in the Picker view?

```
Picker("", selection: $selectedCategory) {
    ForEach(categorySM.categories, id: \.self) { category in
        HStack {
            if let inputImage = UIImage(data: category.image ?? Data()) {
                Image(uiImage: inputImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            Text(category.name ?? "")
        }
        .tag(category as CategoryItem?)
    }
}
.font(.callout)
.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

As you can see in images 1 and 2 below, the image in the tag from the `Beverages` category is huge and covers almost the entire screen, it also covers the category name (Beverages). Is there a way to remove or resize the image when displaying it on the tag? Basically to make it look like image #3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird but resizing the `UIImage` before converting to `Image` view solved the issue.

```
    if let inputImage = UIImage(data: category.image ?? Data()) {
        let resizeImage = inputImage.scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
        Image(uiImage: resizeImage)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
    }
```

Code for resizing the `UIImage`

```
    extension UIImage {
        func scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
            // Determine the scale factor that preserves aspect ratio
            let widthRatio = targetSize.width / size.width
            let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
            
            let scaleFactor = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
            
            // Compute the new image size that preserves aspect ratio
            let scaledImageSize = CGSize(
                width: size.width * scaleFactor,
                height: size.height * scaleFactor
            )

            // Draw and return the resized UIImage
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(
                size: scaledImageSize
            )

            let scaledImage = renderer.image { _ in
                self.draw(in: CGRect(
                    origin: .zero,
                    size: scaledImageSize
                ))
            }
            return scaledImage
        }
    }
```